# tum_simulator installation issue in ROS Indigo

Tags: ros, tum-simulator, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting an error like below after cloning the contents from tum_simulator webpage to my ~/catkin_ws/src and then running the command catkin_make

```
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Architecture x86_64 is already built
Creating universal static lib file from architectures x86_64
make[2]: *** 
[tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_magnetic.dir/src/gazebo_ros_magnetic.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_magnetic.dir/all] Error 2
Build done.
Checking required Ubuntu packages ...
make[2]: *** [tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/all] Error 2
ok.
Building ARDroneTool/Lib
Building ARDroneTool/Lib
[  3%] Performing install step for 'ardronelib'
make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add `+' to parent make rule.
[  3%] Completed 'ardronelib'
[  4%] Built target ardronelib
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205954/tum_simulator-installation-issue-in-ros-indigo/) by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 228 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

please try tum_simulator for indigo
https://github.com/dougvk/tum_simulator

---

Originally posted by [Tal](https://answers.ros.org/users/11486/tal/) with karma: 108 on 2015-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0